# Alexa sample utterance can't discern slots based on connector words

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have two simple Alexa questions I am trying to get working:

```
when is the next train from chicago to new york
when is the next train to new york from chicago
```

In both questions above, the first city gets mapped to the origin and the second to the destination, effectively yielding:

```
when is the next train *from* new york *to* chicago
```

instead of

```
when is the next train *to* new york *from* chicago
```

I have my sample utterances set up like this:

```
NextTrainIntent next train from {OriginCity} to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainIntent next train to {DestinationCity} from {OriginCity}
```

I realize that the connector words are being ignored.  But in cases like this, they are critical, because this is how the english language works.  Is there any way to make both questions work?

Comment: Maybe with two different intents.

Comment: Or make Alexa ask for them separately by marking the slots as required and the user has to ask something like ''Alexa ... create a new rail link!'' response ''Where do you like to go?'' ... .

Comment: Two different intents did the trick -- I simply defined a second intent NextTrainIntentToFrom, and mapped the second sample utterance to it.  Now it works like a charm.  If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement these utterances into two different Intents.

```
FirstIntent ... {OriginCity} to {DestinationCity}
SecondIntent ...{DestinationCity} from {OriginCity}
```

Alexa will listen more carefully then.

Or try the Alexa Skill Builder (BETA).

Comment: Using two intents worked for me to solve the problem.